# Click button in s:iterator struts2

Tags: struts2, iterator

I have create a object Music with attributes name,author,artist,path..

Here is code in file **listproduct.jsp**

```
<font color="red"><s:actionerror/></font>
<table align="center">
         <tr>
             <td width="200" style="background: #4682B4">Name song</td>
             <td width="200" style="background: #4682B4">Artist</td>
             <td style="background: #4682B4">Play</td>
             <td style="background: #4682B4">Delete</td>
         </tr>
        <s:iterator value="arrayMusic">
            <tr>
                <td width="200" style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="%{name}" /></td>
                <td width="200" style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:property value="%{artist}" /></td>
                <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:submit name="playBtn" value="Play" theme="simple" action="play"/></td>
                <td style="background: #CCCCCC"><s:submit name="delBtn" value="Delete" theme="simple" action="delete"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
```

In **struts.xml**

```
<action name="play" class="demo.PlaySongAction">
    <result name="success">listproduct.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">listproduct.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="delete" class="demo.DeleteSongAction">
    <result name="success">listproduct.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">listproduct.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I have List arrayMusic with some object Music..s:iterator displayed data of arrayMusic.

In **PlaySongAction**

```
public class PlaySongAction extends ActionSupport {
public PlaySongAction() {

}
public String execute() throws Exception {
    addActionError("display path of Music");

    //Mp3Player is class to play mp3 with path of song
    Mp3Player mp=new Mp3Player("path of song");
    mp.play();
}
}
```

I want to click play button in each rows,its display path at s:actionerror of Music with name in row and get path of song and play song with path correspond.

How can I do?

Comment: I want to get path of music in row to pass to PlaySongAction and play file mp3 with that path.But I don't get path of song in row

Comment: If you are submitting form then create hidden field with path_of_music.